# React - Shorten string based on width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a container with the width: 500px.
In this container there are 2 strings, "iiiiiiiiiiiiiii" and "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM". You can clearly see that the "M" string is a lot wider than the "i" string, but both fit in the 500px screen.
[image]

If i make the container smaller, lets say 350px the M string is too wide and i want to remove some 'M's so it can fit as so:

[image]

In React i have the following data:

```
var i = 'iiiiiiiiiiiiiii';
var M = 'MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM';
var containerWidth = 500;
```

**Based on what information do I shorten the strings?**

I started out with `if string.length > containerWidth / 10`, but thats not right because string-length != width. I can't use `getElementById` and then use `.offsetWidth`

Comment: For me, you can achieve your goal, without using js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that with css only:

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII<br>
  MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
</div>
```

Will result in something like this. Run the snippet for a live demo.

```
---------------------
| IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII|
| MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM...|
---------------------
```